# Looking for some good references on creating best practice unit tests with MVVM

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm tasked with creating a unit test suite for a WPF solution that employs the MVVM design pattern.  I'm looking for any references to help get me started on the right path, especially any references that focus on some best practices for testing view models.

Some of the particular testing challenges of these view models is in testing the dialog workflows and mediator messages that are passed between some of the view models.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share whether your solution already makes use of patterns like Dependency Injection? Are you already using interfaces for the layers? Are you open to mocking frameworks? These influence the direction you take with unit testing.

Comment: The solution doesn't employ any Dependency Injection patterns that I'm aware of.  There are a number of levels of interfaces defined at the model and view model layers.  I know the lowest level view model interface was derived from Josh Smith's MVVM example.  I'm definitely open to using mocking frameworks such as NMock.  I haven't had any experience using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&ProjectName=compositewpf) comes with a reference implementation Stock Trader, it has extensive tests written for all its modules. Its a very good place to start. Install May 2010 guidance and look for the folder RI.

Comment: +1 thanks anivas.  Looks like Prism may require dev team buy in.  Could this be used solely for building a unit test framework as an option?

Comment: You can have a look at this app solely from MVVM perspective and not Prism. Except for few region based tests rest are just view model and service tests.